# how to improve filter ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, filter

I have a filter thats shows if there's match for letters in `first_name` and `last_name`.

I want this filter only show matching elements when letters are strictly equal to beginning of `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
const filterContacts = ({first_name, last_name}) => {
    return first_name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1 
    || last_name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1;
  }
```

So it's not showing me, for example this
[image]

Please, help me to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check if a string starts with a prefix.

```js
const filterContacts = ({ first_name, last_name }) => {
  const prefix = searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()

  return (
    first_name.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(prefix) ||
    last_name.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)
  )
}
```